# am i writing this update query correctly?

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is the sql query i used before i switch to codeigniter

```
UPDATE transaction SET due_amount = to_pay-$payment_amount WHERE id = '$id'
```

with codeigniter

```
$this->db->set('due_amount', 'to_pay-'.$payment_amount, FALSE);                
$this->db->where('id', $id); 
$result = $this->db->update('transaction');
```

in the codeigniter code am i writing $this->db->set correctly?

Regards

Comment: yes i did and its working but just wanted to check is this the correct way of doing this

Comment: Why do you bypass escaping with `set` (third parameter set to `FALSE`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple variants to use the [`update`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#update) function. Yours doesn't look specifically bad (I would however don't bypass escaping if not for a specific reason), maybe you prefer to use an array (or object) to provide the data being updated:

```
$data = array(
    'due_amount' => 'to_pay-'.$payment_amount,
);
$this->db->update('transaction', $data, sprintf('id = %d', $id));
```

Comment: `transaction` is the name of your database table.

Comment: Gihan, codeigniter has some more info to all the functions in the manual as well. That might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
$this->db->where('id', $id); 
$result = $this->db->update('transaction',array('due_amount'=>'to_pay-'.$payment_amount));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think here could be some issue with `$this->db->set`
Standard way of updating content in codeignitor is this

```
$data = array(
           'title' => $title,
           'name' => $name,
           'date' => $date
        );

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

**Produces:** 
UPDATE mytable
SET title = '{$title}', name = '{$name}', date = '{$date}'
WHERE id = $id